# How can get Object mounted on vue2.7 instance?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I have just completely upgraded my project to Vue2.7, which a backported support for Vue3 feature.

Like what I try is, get the object the in vue instance chain, such as
`import Vue from 'vue'; Vue.prototype.$http = http;` but no any method or hook such as `createApp` supported in vue2.7, so how to I access it(the `$http`) in my component?

only what I can do for now just `console.log(getCurrentInstance())`.

And finally get it by `getCurrentInstance().proxy.__proto__.__proto__.$http`, such unpleasant code, is it any other better shortcut to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Just don't do this and import axios instance directly, or use custom composition function for more flexible approach. this.$http is generally an antipattern that dates back to ES5 with no module support. "getCurrentInstance().proxy.__proto__.__proto__.$http" - it should be `getCurrentInstance().proxy.$http`, due to how JS prototypes work, but any way, it's a hack

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using `provide/inject` to make the axios available in all your components.

https://vuejs.org/guide/components/provide-inject.html

Answer (score 0):

Find out the way by warmed-heart people Jacek, just use `provide` and `inject` to solve it.

Just like

```
const vue = new Vue({
  setup() {
    provide('http', http)
  }, ...
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).